# How to plot the trajectory of points given as list of (latitude, longitude) pairs on a 3D globe?

Tags: matlab, 3d, matlab-figure

I have a 2x1000 matrix with latitude values in 1st row and longitude values in 2nd row.

I want to plot a trajectory using these values on a 3D globe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get some inspiration [here](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/map/working-with-the-globe-display.html), and then use the [`plot3m`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/plot3m.html?searchHighlight=plot3m) function.

Here is an exemple:

```
% Create the globe with graticule
axesm('globe');
gridm('GLineStyle','-','Gcolor',[.8 .7 .6],'Galtitude', .02);    
load coast
plot3m(lat,long,.01,'k');

% Define lat and long
lat = sort(360*rand(50,1));
lon = 180*rand(50,1);

% Plot trajectory
h = plot3m(lat,lon,'r.-', 'MarkerSize', 20);
view(3);
```

[image]

Comment: Please note that this requires the [Mapping Toolbox](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/map/index.html)